# How can I use VST instruments?

Tags: sound, multimedia

I have some VST instruments I would like to use on Ubuntu. How do I get them to work? What host applications are available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running VST Plugins on Ubuntu Linux by Building Ardour with VST Support. A complete step by step tutorial is here

http://noisyheron.wordpress.com/2009/04/05/running-vst-plugins-on-ubuntu-linux-by-building-ardour-with-vst-support/

and one more, LMMS tutorial on where to get VST instruments or effects and how to add them.

http://brycecoulson.com/tutorials/vstinstruments/.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you'll have to load it with some Windows application under Wine

Also you could try you luck with Google: ardourvst

Comment: Or just go here https://web.archive.org/web/20221127014019/https://manual.ardour.org/working-with-plugins/windows-vst-support/