# How to install vst plugins with wine

Tags: wine, plugins, vst

I have FL studio 10 installed on my PC through wine and it works perfect. The pre-installed vst's work but any I install (sylenth1, nexus2 and pianoteq) don't work. I have massive installed and it works. I am a little new to Linux but know the basics.

Comment: Hi  as far as I could find out from here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyhGi8XmL2U  they just copy the dll and then check in FL studio 10 and then are able to start them. Did you do it that way? or what do you mean with "you installed them"?

Answer (score 0):

I installed them with the .exe and then moved the .dll to the specified folders. FL recognizes them, it just shows a grey box saying "loading plugin" and I can choose my preset sounds but the GUI doesn't work i.e. can't play keys on piano, knobs wont move.

Comment: I am not a wine specialist. Maybe you could manage to get wine work better. Sometimes there are just some packages missing. But another possibility would be a parallel install of windows or an installation of Win in a virtual box or vmware. Another try would be using "playOnLinux". This soft could help you in configurin wine. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've been marginally successful in using [Reaper](http://reaper.fm/) under wine. Their website even states

> The Windows version also works well with WINE.

After an install of Reaper, I've copied expanded VST folders into a folder mentioned in it's VST path options. It seems to pick most of them up well. I'm was pretty impressed with the outcome.

Now there is also a project, I've not used but have been really curious about called [Juce](https://launchpad.net/~fabian+roli/+archive/ubuntu/juce). From [reading](http://artandlogic.com/2013/02/developing-audio-applications-with-juce-part-1/) about it, it appears to be a stand alone utility to host native (no emulation) VST instruments.

I've also read another SE answer, that talks about [building Ardour with VST support](https://askubuntu.com/a/89032/57914).

Comment: JUCE is a programming library for building (programming in C++) plugins. If you are searching for a quick plugin host, there are Carla or jalv. 
I've exercised one month about the future of my audio projects, and I decided to use DPF (DISTRHO Plugin Framework), which supports things very well and ... Not the costs of JUCE - on the other hand JUCE is THE standard for programming plugins. 
Anyway, DISTRHO is nice...