# Audio PC Software running on UBUNTU

Tags: sound, vst

I recently built my own home studio PC. i5 CPU) 8Gb RAM, solid state drive etc. Basically the fastest PC I've ever built. I have a 32bit version of Windows XP and all the music software I have runs on this. However, I want to use all the RAM and can only do so by moving to 64bit Windows.

My questions are:
Will Ubuntu run my Audio software or would I need to get Linux specific Audio software?

Are there any good (pro) shareware Linux based multi-track audio software packages?

Will VST plug-ins work through UBUNTU?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is very unlikely that your Windows Audio software will run without latency with Ubuntu. You may be able to run it with the [compatibilty layer Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9372/how-can-i-run-windows-applications-in-ubuntu) but it is unlikely that they will perform as expected. Due to latency running Windows audio applications in a virtual machine is not an option.

However there are quite a few alternatives for Ubuntu that may meet your needs (even though they will be different to the Windows counterparts):

- **Jack** is an audio server with a more professional ambition.
- **Ardour** is a multitrack audio processing tool that can be built [with support for VST](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89024/how-can-i-use-vst-instruments).
- **Rosegarden** is a full blown, highly configurable MIDI sequencer
- **Audacity** is a professional audio wave editor
- and many many more.

All these applications can be easily installed and fairly easily configured in a standard 64-bit Ubuntu desktopb edition. You may however be interested in the especially for audio, graphic, and video highly customized derivative where most of these applications are already installed:

- [Ubuntu Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org/)